# Floating label for an html select element

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to a make a floating label for a select element, so when you focus on the the field the label floats above it. If you select an option the label should stay above the field and if you haven't selected anything it should drop down again.

The problem is that when an option is selected the label drops down on the selected option rather than staying a float above it.

I can bind the onclick event on the selected element to achieve this, but I'm looking for a pure css solution.

See the following code:

```css
.floating-label { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:20px; 
}

.floating-select {
  font-size:14px;
  padding:4px 4px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}

.floating-select:focus {
     outline:none;
     border-bottom:2px solid #5264AE; 
}

label {
  color:#999; 
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:5px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}

.floating-select:focus ~ label , .floating-select:not([value=""]):valid ~ label {
  top:-18px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#5264AE;
}

/* active state */
.floating-select:focus ~ .floating-select:focus ~  {
  width:50%;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* active state */
 .floating-select:focus ~  {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<br>
    <div class="floating-label">  
      <select class="floating-select">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Item1</option>
        <option value="2">Item2</option>
        <option value="3">Item3</option>
        <option value="4">Item4</option>
        <option value="5">Item5</option>
      </select>
      <label>Select</label>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a pure css solution that supports mobile devices as well. So the following solution is not good enough:

```
...
<select onclick="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">...</select>
...
```